# TeX table - same code but different format

Tags: tables, threeparttable

I have a problem with tables in TeX.
I get different tables using following code in different sections of the document. Some separation lines in the header are missing but always different lines.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{threeparttable}[H]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{6.5cm}|X|X|X|X|X|}
\firsthline
\rowcolor[gray]{0.8} \textbf{Anforderung }&\textbf{\tnote{1}}&\textbf{\tnote{2} }&\textbf{\tnote{3} }&\textbf{\tnote{4}}&\textbf{\tnote{5} }\\\hline
1.1 SQL"=Injections&0&0,077&0&0,077&0,077\\\hline
\lasthline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Nutzwerte aller Werkzeuge}
\label{Tabelle:Nutzwerte}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{center}
```

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Just try zooming in or out (or printing) lines next to coloured panels will vanish in some pdf viewers at some zoom levels just due to pixel rounding artefacts.

Comment: Your´re right. The lines were just vanished in the viewer. Thanks.